# Accessing data from cartesian list of files

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a numerous csv files in a folder that I have turned into a cartesian list as such:

```
import os 
import itertools

filelist=os.listdir(r'pathway_to_folder')
result = list(itertools.product(filelist,filelist))
```

the contents of result are like this:

```
('file 1', 'file 2')
('file 1', 'file 3')
('file 2', 'file 1')
('file 2', 'file 3')
('file 3', 'file 1')
('file 3', 'file 2')
```

how would I even do something as simple as printing out the contents of one item in `result`?  As of now they are just recognized as strings from what I can tell.

Comment: Do you want read the file content?

Comment: exactly, eventually I want to do a statistical test on each item in `result` but I don't know how to recognize the files for what they are and not strings

Comment: What type are these files? csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need to print content of the files which are in csv format. You could do that with `pandas` [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
for files in result:
    print(pd.read_csv(files[0]), pd.read_csv(files[1])
```

*Note:* You need to pass full path to the files in `read_csv` function. You could do that with `os.path.abspath` to the each element e.g. `pd.read_csv(os.path.abspath(files[0]))`

Answer (score 1):

Iterating on each item may help

```
for t in result:
    for fn in t:
        with open (fn) as f:
            for line in f:
                print (line) # or whatever
```

As mentioned in the comments,  there are probably better ways to achieve your goals,  depending on what they are.

E.g use one or more specific libraries like `csv`, `numpy`, `pandas`, etc.